# How do I play the official "Left 2 Die" scenario?

Tags: starcraft-2

Several of the achievements under the arcade section of StarCraft 2 are for a game named "left 2 die". When I looked that up in the list of arcade games, there are six pages of results, but none of them are the official scenario made by Blizzard.

Where can I find this scenario in order to unlock the achievements?

Comment: select show as "Top Rated" and genre as "Survival". it'll be one of the highest ones there

Comment: @Aequitas Found it. But is that seriously the only way to find it? :O. What if people started giving it a low rating? Would it disappear forever?

Comment: Blizzard will probably fix it if that happens.

Comment: Aiur Chef has the same problem. Can't find it anywhere.

Comment: I submitted a bug report: http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/20044776983

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [reported a bug](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/20044776983) and received the following response from Blizard:

> There's a known issue where the arcade's general search function does
>   not return a complete list of results so that may be why you you are
>   not finding it. Like aYeDeeKay mentioned, try looking for it on the
>   Top Rated/Played lists instead.

It looks like the issue I was facing was resolved in a recent patch.